# Why i can automate .ipa file in browserstack but not simulator

Tags: ios, testing, automated-tests, appium, browserstack

Just wonder how browserstack overcome provisioning files and all that
I only have bundleId capability included and app uploaded through their API

When trying same set up on local machine with simulator OR real device app, i`m not able to automate app in any way

Answer (score 0):

Basically iOS app has three different file formats(.ipa, .app, .zip).
Assuming that you are using Appium for automating the app.

- In real device .ipa and .zip formats will work, but you have to setup the apple developer id and link your mac and the real device.
- In Browserstack app automate also .ipa and .zip formats will work because internally it uses real devices, but you need to upload the file to Browserstack using the API
- In xcode simulators only .zip format will work

.app format I have not tested, so I cannot comment about that

All these file formats can be generated by signing the app using developer certificate